# How do you remove silkscreen footprint in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

When I change a component from the top to the bottom layer it leaves the shape of the object in the silkscreen of the top layer as shown in the picture. I have tried deleting it but I cant select the overlay separately from the component and I cant unlock the primitives from the properties panel of the components.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's the top silk layer you're seeing and not some other layer with the same color scheme? Your component designators have flipped from top silk to bottom...

Comment: Ideally you would want to attach "View Configuration" window as well so that we can see which layer the yellow outline is used on.
If you still can't figure it out. Disable all layers in "View Configuration" and re-enable one by one till you find out which layer is it on (in case you can not select it)

Answer (score 1):

Some footprints have silkscreen on both top and bottom layers, so flipping the component to the opposite side flips the top/bottom silkscreen as well. In either case, you can selectively remove objects from placed components without modifying the library by doing the following:

1. Select the component
2. In the properties panel, uncheck the lock on **Primitives**
3. Select the specific item you want to remove (select the appropriate layer first as needed)
4. Delete the item
5. Re-lock the **primitives** option after selecting the component again. If you can't select the component easily, you can use the **PCB Panel** (View -> Panels -> PCB).

Answer (score 0):

The yellow color is a fab/mechanical layer, not silkscreen.

So, to answer your question of "how to delete it": you don't need to nor want to. Plot it to Gerber and see for yourself that there's nothing on the top silkscreen.